# Determine empty template variable in Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-templates, pymongo

I'm not able to determine whether a variable is empty when used in the template.
I've iterated through the whole collection and in each I'm looking for a variable `narrative_text`.

I tested the empty variable by

```
{% ifnotequal narratives.narrative_text '' %}
```

I notice the control enters this block, but prints nothing/blank when the

```
{{  narratives.narrative_text }}
```

is encountered.

So, how do I precisely check if the variable is empty?

I read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables) and found out that invalid/empty template variables are replaced by `''`.

The doc says that

> the template system inserts the value of the `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` setting.

Do we have to explicitly enter that into the `settings.py`? I tried doing so but still I haven't been able to make it work.

```
c=Context({ 
    "narratives_list":all_narratives,
    "patient_name":care_seeker_name
})
```

`all_narratives` is returned by a pymongo database call.

```
{%  for narratives in narratives_list  %}
<tr>
<td class = "date_col">
    7 Aug, 2012
</td>
{%  ifnotequal narratives.narrative_text '' %}
<td>
<div class = "narrative">
    ( text narrative )
<b> 
    {{ narratives.about }}
</b>
<br><br>
{{ narratives.narrative_text }}
</div>  
</td>   
{%  else %}
<td>
<div class="scans">
<div class="gallery">
<b> {{ narratives.about }}</b>
<br><br>
<a href="https://udhc1-nodejstest.rhcloud.com/my_image/{{ narratives.file_id }}">
<img src="https://udhc1-nodejstest.rhcloud.com/my_image/{{ narratives.file_id }}" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
</a>
</div>
</div>
</td>
{%  endifnotequal %}
```

Comment: Django will also display nothing if an error occurs, e.g. if the name does not exist.

Comment: Thanks @HansThen then it should return a 'false' when compared using ifnotequals with ''
?

Comment: I thought it'd skip the whole block. Basically error means forget this  statement. Also inside of an if.

Comment: What should be the workaround?

Comment: To debug, check that `narratives_list` is not empty. If it is not, check if the `else` block is printed. If it is not, you know you have an error. Otherwise, you can check in the code (not the template) to see what's in these variables, using a logging.debug() statement.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Pipe through length and do your test against that value.

```
{% if narratives.narrative_text|length > 0 %}
    {{ narratives.narrative_text }}
{% else %}
    None
{% endif %}
```

Comment: this is so ugly but good solution Wade. I'm starting to understand why people call jinja2 superior to django templates

Answer (score 7):

Just use `{% if narratives.narrative_text %}`, I think. It will use Python's implicit false, which applies for empty strings, empty arrays, empty dicts, `None`, `False`, `0` etc..

Comment: Thanks @Torsen I tried this. The 'if th.en' block got skipped even when the narratives.narrative_text was not empty

Answer (score 4):

Just confirmed via my own code using django 2.1.3 and python 3.5 and 3.7 that the following works:

```
{% if narratives.narrative_text %}
    # do something
    {{ narratives.narrative_text }}
{% else %}
    # do something else
    None  # displays "None" 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that the best and obvious solution would be, in Django Template language:

```
{% if objects is not None %}
    {% for obj in objects %}
        {{obj}}   // Do your stuff here
    {% empty %}
        No results.    // No results case
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

In case the variable `objects` is not set, nothing will be printed out.

I had similar difficulties.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the most concise way to handle an empty list should you need to print out a message in the template noting it.

Answer (score 2):

You can write [Custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters), `is_empty` to check. Return `false` if variable is empty and `true` if value exists.

```
{% if narratives.narrative_text|is_empty %}
    # dosomthing 
{% else %}
    # dosomthing 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used [jijnja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) which is a lot similar and simpler and I think it would work if you do

```
{% if not narratives.narrative_text %}
  // do something 
{% else %}
 // do something else  with or without {{ narratives.narrative_text }}
{% endif %}
```

It uses python implicit `True/False,None,` etc to do the job.
In simplest terms use  python variables inside `{{ }}` and conditionals,etc inside `{% %}`

Comment: Work's like a charm. I could not understand why this answer was voted negative. Thank you emiljho.